# Remove all the [tags]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[image]

The description on [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags) is:

> A tag is a marker or semantic descriptor. Despite generic origin this "tag" has become synonymous with HTML - if your question is already within this context, it's use is likely unnecessary.

It currently has <s>5,800</s> <s>6763</s> <s>9357</s> 10224 questions and <s>32</s> <s>34</s> <s>192</s> 314 watchers, but most of the top answerers are users who have answered only one question. It's not really a helpful tag or adds much to a question (imo).

Request to burninate.

Comment: Says the excerpt: 'it's' <sic>.

Comment: Your image graphic threw a  `NotValidMemeException`.  [See here for correct example](http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZSiNy3Z37DnkdBZ3atfs6Obm3HOOAn3GfX7_ns0jN7iS7LuK0).

Comment: Meh it's only a meme

Comment: Filtering all questions featuring one of "[html] [php] [javascript] [jsp] [xml] [html5] [css] [asp.net]", there are 3047 questions left, more than half. I'm not convinced those should really loose the tag tag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags+-html+-php+-javascript+-jsp+-xml+-html5+-css+-asp.net Maybe you just wanted a drastic clean-up?

Comment: @Deduplicator I dunno a lot of those questions have "tag" tag just to bloat them, I mean take the very latest question, adding that tag because you want to make a facebook tagging system? This tag may have been rightfully  used by some but that has been drowned out by the many who have used it for the fun of having that many tags

Comment: @Sammaye: Without doubt, thus a drastic clean-up would be right, not a burnination. Though I must confess there are too many questions to check for my taste.

Comment: Don't forget [tag-manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-manipulation), because what is the point if they can't be manipulated?

Comment: Tags in the context of source control systems ([like git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags+git)) is an important use.  But maybe another tag should be created for that to avoid it attracting barnacles.

Comment: @JasonMArcher [git-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-tag) already exists

Comment: [tags] makes no sense as a standalone tag. Tags only make sense as specific tags within a specific framework. [tagging] should be able to cover most cases, where [tags] is correctly used in a generic way. Coexistence of [tags] and [tagging] feels redundant.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe. [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags) are the main concept of HTML and HTML is all about tags. There are specific versions of this, such as [html-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-input) but all of the questions that are tagged "tags" are about HTML. So just let "tags" get into the greater, broader world of HTML.

But wait, *I'm wrong*.

Currently, there 9,455 questions tagged [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags) and also 2,433 questions that are both tagged [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags) and [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html). When I searched for questions that have the word "html" in them, there were 8,422 questions. About 1/4 of all [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags) questions have [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) also and about 9/10 of all questions have the word "html" in them. I suggest the 2433 questions who have both [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags) would be moved to "html-tags". The other questions would stay tagged "tags".