# This [tag] doesn't really belong here

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Believe it or not, we have a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) tag. Currently, 8,769 questions (349 of which are already closed).

The tag usage guidance is pretty worthless:

> A tag is a marker or semantic descriptor. Despite generic origin this "tag" has become synonymous with HTML - if your question is already within this context, its use is likely unnecessary. In different context, however, the term "tags" can also be officially used. One case would be in a SCADA program Ignition, where tag is one of the basic units placed in hierarchical system, each having its own tag-path and tag-relative paths towards others.

Great! So even after reading that wall of text, I *still* have no idea when this tag is supposed to be used. So basically, it's mostly for HTML, but maybe it's for other uses to?

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No, even the tag Wiki is really vague as to when you should use it.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Maybe...

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Not really.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Even the tag Wiki admits otherwise.

Can we send this (rather useless) [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) to Trogdor?

Comment: I don't believe it.

Comment: Related, currently it is a synonym https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272112/remove-all-the-tags?rq=1

Comment: [Tag], Trogdor, you're it!

Comment: `<burn>[tag]</burn>` ?

Comment: @Cœur Not really. That post proposed doing away with "tags" rather than "tag". However, I do think that both are unnecessary.

Comment: @Blackwood it's the same tag, they are synonyms.

Comment: That tag is a bad tag yes!, but  8,769 questions.... that's several 100 of hours reviewing.. does it really do that much harm that we should invest this time, I would say no and use the reviewing time for more harmful tags.

Comment: I want to tag this with tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree; I cannot think of a use of the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) tag where it would add useful information to the post. If I filtered questions by it, I cannot predict what kind of questions I would get.

Comment: Bad ones presumably

Answer (score 4):

[tags] would be far more acceptable in the context of HTML/5, but even that is a stretch. More appropriately, people should use [html-tags].

Answer (score -2):

The description could be written a little better but it's still pretty clear: if you are referring to tags in HTML, then it's not necessary to add the "tag" tag.  Add the "tag" tag if it refers to something specific to a programming language (and it gives the example in SCADA).

Comment: SCADA isn't a programming language

Answer (score -19):

I disagree. Description says if your question is already within the context of HTML it's no needed because it has become synonymous with HTML. However there could be other cases too

Comment: What, exactly, does "other cases" mean though? That seems pretty vague at a minimum. Really, a good tag should have a clear, unambiguous meaning.

Comment: @EJoshuaS It could be an issue with XML or anything related to tags. I'm assuming.

Comment: Yes, the "XML **or**..." part is problematic. That means that the tag is ambiguous. Tags are supposed to clearly identify the actual topic of the question.